# Facebook - How can I make this checkbox checked by default?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

"Also post on Facebook" is not highlighted by default in facebook comment plugin.

How can I enable it so that the visitor who comments, has this checkbox checked by default?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, there is no setting for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

In other words, it is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

set the value for that checkbox by default means the value that will be passed to variable after selecting that check box , you can initialize that variable by default and your check will get selected

Comment: how to pass the value?. Its facebook comment plugin